# bounty bug: the bounty should not go back to the original poster

Tags: support, bounty

Look at this question: [How to pass a 2 dimensional float array from QML to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056776/how-to-pass-a-2-dimensional-float-array-from-qml-to-c/26093904?noredirect=1#comment40890995_26093904). The author promises bounty, I answer, then he quotes me and accepts his own answer. I am not as much angry, as I think this to be a bug. If you put out a bounty, you better give it to someone!

Comment: How is this a bug? The bounty period is not finished. A better answer may yet come. And we don't let people award immediately.

Comment: This is also no feature request - what feature is being requested, exactly?

Comment: The award of a bounty and the acceptance of an answer are totally different. The OP even said in a comment _bounty will be assigned to you after 22 hours._ - so what's the problem?

Comment: Well he accepted his own answer. So that's the best answer.

Comment: @user1095108: what has that got to do with the bounty however?

Comment: @user, there is no problem here, since [the questioner cannot award the bounty to their own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116567/can-i-award-a-bounty-to-myself-if-i-provide-the-best-answer).

Comment: Ok, forgive the noob :) Delete question if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

You don't *have* to award the bounty to anyone.

Also answer acceptance has nothing to do with bounties.

If your answer gains 2 up-votes before the bounty expires then there's a chance that some of the bounty will automatically awarded to you.

Comment: A chance? What's the probability? :)

Comment: @user1095108: 100% provided that a) the bounty isn't manually awarded to someone else, b) no other answers are posted that get voted higher.

Comment: well, except the **half** part - [*"If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, **half** the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever."*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

Comment: @user1095108: note that if the bounty is left to be auto-awarded, only *half* the bounty will be awarded to you, unless your answer was also marked as 'accepted'.